# Showing that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\max_{y\in[x,x+h]}f(y)=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $x\in[a,b]$. I would like to show that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\max_{y\in[x,x+h]} f(y)=f(x).$$

Since for $h>0$ such that $x+h\in[a,b]$, we get $f(x)\leq\max_{y\in[x,x+h]}f(y)$, we can conclude that
$$f(x)\leq\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\max_{y\in[x,x+h]} f(y).$$

I can't figure out how to show $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\max_{y\in[x,x+h]} f(y)\leq f(x)$. Any hints?

Comment: How does continuity of $f$ help you here?

Comment: @DavidKraemer it ensures that $\max_{y\in[x,x+h]}f(y)$ exists (by extreme value theorem).

Comment: *Hint.* For each $h:=\frac1n$, there is a $x_n\in[x,x+h]$ such that $f(x_n)=\max_{y\in[x,x+h]}f(y)$. Can you check that $x_n\to x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then by continuity of $f$ at $x$, it exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for $x \le y \le x +\delta$ we have

$$f(y) \le f(x) +\epsilon.$$

This implies that

$$\max\limits_{y \in [x,x+h]} f(y) \lt f(x)+\epsilon$$ for all $0 \le h \le \delta$. As this is true for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, we get the desired inequality.

Comment: thank you. How do we ensure $\delta\leq b-x$? E.g. if $x=b$ then such a $\delta$ cannot exists---Actually, what I'm trying to prove cannot make hold at $x=b$ since $f$ isn't even defined at $[b,b+h]$..correct? How should I modify it for the case $x=b$?

Comment: For $x \in [a,b]$, you can define $F_x(h) = \max\limits_{y \in [x, x+h] \cap [a,b]} f(y)$. Then $F_b(h)$ is well defined for any $h \gt 0$.